# Evaluate $I_n = \int_0^{\pi / 2} \sin n \theta \cos \theta \,d\theta$ by integrating by parts twice

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

By integrating by parts twice, show that $I_n$, as defined below for integers $n > 1$, has the value shown.

> $$I_n = \int_0^{\pi / 2} \sin n \theta \cos \theta \,d\theta = \frac{n-\sin(\frac{\pi n}{2})}{n^2 -1}$$

I can do this using the formula $$\sin A \cos B = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(A-B)+\sin(A+B)] ,$$ but when I try using integration by parts I get stuck in a loop of integrating the same thing over and over.

Comment: Please [format your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a bit more; there are apparently some unreadable characters.

Comment: Can you describe a little more the choices that lead to getting "stuck in a loop"?

Comment: @Travis let theta=x so it's quicker for me to type... so, after the first IBP i get sin(x)sin(nx) - Intergral [n(sin(x)cos(nx))]. when i use IBP on this integral i get sin(x)sin(nx) - Integral [cos(x)sin(nx)] which is what i originally tried to integrate ..

Comment: @T.Bongers i did try my best. i'm new to this.

Comment: I think that there are some non-Unicode symbols being included in the equation (to the right of the second equality).

Comment: @Taylor I took the liberty of fixing the minor formatting issues discussed in the earlier comments. You might find it instructive to look at the modified markup code to pick up some more basics.

Comment: BTW, this integral is a good candidate for applying the double integration by parts formula, $\int f g'' \,dx = f g' - f' g + \int f'' g \,dx$.

Comment: Interestingly, by using the product-to-sum formula, you cancel the need for by-parts integration and get a direct solution. It seems that you tried anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Following what you've done already, integrating by parts with $u = \sin n \theta$, $dv = \cos \theta \,d\theta$ gives
\begin{multline}\color{#df0000}{I_n} = \underbrace{\sin n \theta}_u \, \underbrace{\sin \theta}_v \vert_0^{\pi / 2} - \int_0^{\pi / 2} \underbrace{\sin \theta}_v \, \underbrace{\cos n\theta \, d\theta}_{du} = \sin \frac{\pi n}{2} - n \color{#1f1fff}{J_n}, \\ \color{#1f1fff}{J_n := \int_0^{\pi / 2} \cos n \theta \sin \theta \, d\theta} .\end{multline}

We now apply integration by parts to the integral $\color{#3f3fff}{J_n}$ with $p = \cos n \theta$, $dq = \sin \theta \,d\theta$:
$$\color{#3f3fff}{J_n} = \cos n \theta (-\cos \theta)\vert_0^{\pi / 2} - \int_0^{\pi / 2} \underbrace{-\cos \theta}_q \cdot \underbrace{- n \sin n \theta \,d\theta}_{dp} = 1 - n \color{#df0000}{I_n} .$$

> Substituting to eliminate $\color{#3f3fff}{J_n}$ gives $\color{#df0000}{I_n} = \sin \frac{\pi n}{2} - n (1 - n \color{#df0000}{I_n})$, and rearranging to solve for $\color{#df0000}{I_n}$ gives the claimed identity: $$\color{#df0000}{\boxed{I_n = \frac{n - \sin \frac{\pi n}{2}}{n^2 - 1}}} .$$ Notice that for $n \equiv 0, 2 \pmod 4$ this simplifies to $\frac{n}{n^2 - 1}$, for $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ to $\frac{1}{n + 1}$, and for $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ to $\frac{1}{n - 1}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos{(x)} \sin{\left( n x\right) }=\frac{\sin{\left( \left( n+1\right)  x\right) }+\sin{\left( \left( n-1\right)  x\right) }}{2}$$
$$\int{\left. \cos{(x)} \sin{\left( n x\right) }dx\right.}=-\frac{\cos{\left( \left( n+1\right)  x\right) }}{2 \left( n+1\right) }-\frac{\cos{\left( \left( n-1\right)  x\right) }}{2 \left( n-1\right) }$$
Then
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\left. \cos{(x)} \sin{\left( n x\right) }dx\right.}\\=
\frac{n}{n^2-1}-\frac{\left( n-1\right)  \cos{\left( \frac{{\pi}  n+{\pi} }{2}\right) }+\left( n+1\right)  \cos{\left( \frac{{\pi}  n-{\pi} }{2}\right) }}{2n^2-2}\\=
\frac{n}{{{n}^{2}}-1}-\frac{\sin{\left( \frac{{\pi}  n}{2}\right) }}{{{n}^{2}}-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

There's an escape from the infinite loop. If you observe closely, you will see that after two iterations you get to something like

$$I=b+aI$$

where the constants $a,b$ are computable.

You naturally conclude

$$I=\frac{b}{1-a}.$$

---

> $$\int\sin n\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta=\sin n\theta\sin\theta-n\int\cos n\theta\sin\theta\,d\theta\\=\sin n\theta\sin\theta+n\cos n\theta\cos\theta+n^2\int\sin n\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta.$$